# Number of divisors which are at most $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, divisors-multiples

I’m interested in the function $\tau_n:\mathbb{N}\to\{1,2,3,\cdots, n\}$ defined by
$$\tau_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{k\mid x},$$
the number of divisors of $x$ which are at most $n$. Question 6 of the 2023 Miklós Schweitzer competition is to show that, for sufficiently large $n$, $\tau_n$ is surjective. I’m interested in a solution to this. I’m also interested to see if the function $\tau_n$ has been studied before, I would greatly appreciate a reference.

I’ve worked on this problem a little bit, and here are some of my ideas. It may be fruitful to consider the summatory function
$$\mathcal{T}_n(X)=\sum_{x=1}^X\tau_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl\lfloor \frac{X}{k}\Bigr\rfloor.$$
This may also turn out to be a Chinese Remainder Theorem thing, considering residue classes modulo prime powers.

Comment: The opposite question is also interesting: are there values of $n$ for which it isn't surjective?

Comment: @PeterTaylor "Command Master" has verified surjectivity for $n\leq 61000$ while I proved surjectivity for $n>61000$. So (if our work is correct) $\tau_n$ is surjective for all $n$.

Comment: Surjectivity for all $n$ was already known. For the unofficial solution, and the history of the problem, see the following two links (and use a translator if needed): https://www.math.u-szeged.hu/~vigvik/schweitzer/elozetes_schw_megold.pdf and https://ematlap.hu/hetproba-3/1331-schweitzer-7tusa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to prove that $\tau_n$ is surjective for $n$ large enough.

Denote by $P_n$ the set of primes $\le n$.
$\tau_n(x)$ depends only on powers of primes from $P_n$ in the decomposition of $x$.
Divide $P_n$ into three subsets. $P_n^1$ — primes that are bigger than $n/2$, $P_n^2$ — primes that are $\le 3 \log n$. And $P_n^3$ — other primes.
Note that $|P_n^1| > \frac{n}{3 \log n}$ for $n$ large enough.
Let $m \in \{1, 2, \dotsc, n \}$. We want to find $x$ such that $\tau_n(x) = m$.

Assume that we found $x$ not divisible by any prime in $P_n^1$ and such that
\begin{equation} \tag{1}\label{1}
\tau_n(x) \in [m - |P_n^1|, m]. 
\end{equation}
Then we can take $k := m - \tau_n(x)$ primes from the set $P_n^1$, say $p_1, \dotsc, p_k$, and then $\tau_n(p_1\dotsm p_k x) = m$.

So it is enough to find $x$ satisfying \eqref{1}.
Take $x = 1$. We will modify $x$ in such way that on each step

$$\tau_n(x_\text{new}) - \tau_n(x_\text{old}) < \frac{n}{3 \log n} < |P_n^1|. \tag{2}\label{2}$$
If finally $x$ is divisible by every number in $\{1, \dotsc, n \} \setminus P_n^1$, we are done, because then $\tau_n(x) = n - |P_n^1|$ and at some step the condition \eqref{1} had to be satisfied.

First let $x = x_\text{new}$ be the product of primes in $P_n^2$ in big powers.
Then $\tau_n(x)$ is the number of $3 \log n$-smooth numbers that are less than $n$. From the theory of smooth numbers we know, that this is $O(n^{\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. In particular it is $< \frac{n}{3\log n}$ for $n$ large enough and hence \eqref{2} is satisfied.

Then on each step we can take $x_\text{new} = p^{n} x_\text{old}$, where $p$ is any prime in $P_n^3$ that does not divide $x_\text{old}$. It is clear that
$$
\tau_n(x_\text{new}) - \tau_{n}(x_\text{old}) \le \left[ \frac{n}{p} \right] < \frac{n}{3 \log n}.
$$
This competes the proof.

Comment: It seems that $\tau_n$ is surjective for all $n$. See my response and Command Master's comments below it.

Comment: Surjectivity for all $n$ was already known. See the two links in my second comment under the original post.

Answer (score 6):

This is a supplement to Petr Kucheryavy's very nice proof. I claim that $\tau_n$ is surjective for $n>5\cdot 10^{13}$. (In fact one can extend this range to $n>60151$ by more concrete estimations. See the "Added" section. Moreover, "Command Master" has further extended this range to all $n>0$, see the link to the code in the comments section. So it seems that $\tau_n$ is surjective for all $n$.)

**1.** First we observe that $|P_n^1| >n/(2\log n)$ holds for all $n>3298$ (while it fails for $n=3298$). This is clear for $n>11000$ by Corollary 5.3 in Dusart: Explicit estimates of some functions over primes, Ramanujan Journal 45 (2018), and it can be checked in the remaining cases by SAGE. This means that we can replace $3\log n$ by $2\log n$ in Petr Kucheryavy's proof, and it remains to show that
$$\Psi(n,2\log n)<\frac{n}{2\log n},\qquad n>5\cdot 10^{13}.\tag{$\ast$}$$

**2.** To verify $(\ast)$, we apply Theorem A.1 from Lichtman-Pomerance: Explicit estimates for the distribution of numbers free of large prime factors, Journal of Number Theory 183 (2018):
$$\Psi(x,y)\leq 1.39\frac{y^{1-\sigma}}{\log x}x^\sigma\prod_{p\leq y}(1-p^{-\sigma})^{-1},\qquad \frac{1}{\log y}\leq\sigma\leq 1.$$
We estimate the logarithm of the Euler product on the right-hand side as
$$\sum_{p\leq y}-\log(1-p^{-\sigma})\leq -2^\sigma\log(1-2^{-\sigma})\sum_{p\leq y}p^{-\sigma}.$$
We further estimate the last sum as follows.
$$\sum_{p\leq y}p^{-\sigma}=\int_{2-}^y \frac{t^{-\sigma}}{\log t}d\theta(t)=\frac{y^{-\sigma}}{\log y}\theta(y)+\int_2^y\left(\frac{-t^{-\sigma}}{\log t}\right)'\theta(t)\,dt.$$
Note that the derivative in the last expression is positive. Applying the bound $\theta(x)<1.002 x$ furnished by Theorem 6 of Rosser-Schenfeld: Sharper bounds for the Chebyshev functions $\theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)$, Mathematics of Computation 29 (1975), it follows that
$$\frac{1}{1.002}\sum_{p\leq y}p^{-\sigma}<\frac{y^{1-\sigma}}{\log y}+\int_2^y\left(\frac{-t^{-\sigma}}{\log t}\right)'t\,dt.$$
We can rewrite this as
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1.002}\sum_{p\leq y}p^{-\sigma}&<\frac{2^{1-\sigma}}{\log 2}+\left[\frac{t^{1-\sigma}}{\log t}\right]_2^y+\int_2^y\left(\frac{-t^{-\sigma}}{\log t}\right)'t\,dt\\
&=\frac{2^{1-\sigma}}{\log 2}+\int_2^y\frac{t^{-\sigma}}{\log t}dt\\
&=\frac{2^{1-\sigma}}{\log 2}+\int_{(1-\sigma)\log 2}^{(1-\sigma)\log y}\frac{e^r}{r}dr\\
&=\frac{2^{1-\sigma}}{\log 2}-\mathrm{Ei}((1-\sigma)\log 2)+\mathrm{Ei}((1-\sigma)\log y).
\end{align*}
In the end, we obtain the explicit bound
$$\Psi(x,y)<1.39\frac{y^{1-\sigma}}{\log x}x^\sigma\exp\bigl\{c_\sigma d_\sigma+c_\sigma\mathrm{Ei}((1-\sigma)\log y)\bigr\},\tag{2}$$
where
$$c_\sigma:=-1.002\cdot 2^\sigma\log(1-2^{-\sigma})\qquad\text{and}\qquad d_\sigma:=\frac{2^{1-\sigma}}{\log 2}-\mathrm{Ei}((1-\sigma)\log 2).\tag{3}$$
We apply this bound with $\sigma:=0.55$, and $(\ast)$ follows. (I have not checked this last step formally, but Mathematica convincingly shows this, and that is sufficient for me.)

**Added.** One can extend the validity of $(\ast)$ to $n>6\cdot 10^6$ by calculating the Euler product over $p\leq 2\log n$ directly when $5\cdot 10^{13}\geq n>6\cdot 10^6$, and optimizing $\sigma$ for specific intervals within this range. For $n\leq 6\cdot 10^6$, the left-hand side of $(\ast)$ can be calculated explicitly by SAGE. This way one can check that $n=60151$ is the largest value for which $(\ast)$ fails; for this particular $n$, the left-hand side is $2733$, while the right-hand side is a bit smaller.

Comment: I confirmed with a computer that it's surjective for $n \leq 10000$, but it was getting slow. I think I thought of a more efficient algorithm, I'll try to implement it

Comment: Running [this code](https://gist.github.com/Command-Master/cee4ba4b8cf9656f2de933b57e1c4cca) (compile with `-O2`, it took an hour on my computer) shows surjectiveness for $n < 61000$ (unless there's a bug in my code), so it's surjective for all $n$.

Comment: @CommandMaster That's wonderful news! I updated the first paragraph in my answer accordingly.

Comment: @CommandMaster Surjectivity for all $n$ was already known. See the two links in my second comment under the original post.